# How to fix wrong formated date vector from csv file

Tags: r, csv, date

I have data from a csv file that when imported to R looks like this ( last row value of DisChargeDate field is wrong):

```
            VisitDate      VisitHour DisChargeDate DisChargeHour  
              01/12/2012  14:24:33    01/13/2012      00:34:09
              01/12/2012  14:29:07    01/12/2012      18:40:01
              01/12/2012  19:20:39    01/12/2012      20:56:11
              01/12/2012  19:43:40     1/13/2012      01:53:50
```

How can I fix this issue so I'll be able to change the variable for date format like in the code below that works file If I remove the last row:

```
library(lubridate)
df$visitDateTime<-with(df, dmy(DisChargeDate ) + hms(DisChargeHour))
```

Comment: Base-R `as.Date(df$DisChargeDate, "%m/%d/%Y")` seems to deal with the situation just fine...

Comment: That's wierd. I am not familiar with lubridate so let's hope someone else can answer..

Comment: Thank you snoram, I'll post the error as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace `dmy()` by `mdy()` e.g.:

```
library(lubridate)
df$visitDateTime<-with(df, mdy(DisChargeDate ) + hms(DisChargeHour))

   VisitDate VisitHour DisChargeDate DisChargeHour       visitDateTime
1 01/12/2012  14:24:33    01/13/2012      00:34:09 2012-01-13 00:34:09
2 01/12/2012  14:29:07    01/12/2012      18:40:01 2012-01-12 18:40:01
3 01/12/2012  19:20:39    01/12/2012      20:56:11 2012-01-12 20:56:11
4 01/12/2012  19:43:40     1/13/2012      01:53:50 2012-01-13 01:53:50
```